# What is the difference between a Technical key and a Surrogate key?

Tags: sql, dns, rdbms, business-intelligence

Is a surrogate key the same as a primary key in an OLTP system?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key

Comment: in every language known to me, questions end with a single "?", not two or three. I hence edited your question.

Comment: @ Marcus Thank you very much, u have done a great job .

Answer (score 0):

Surrogate key is a substitution for the natural primary key.
It is just a unique identifier or number for each row that can be used for the primary key to the table. The only requirement for a surrogate primary key is that it is unique for each row in the table.
Data warehouses typically use a surrogate (also known as artificial or identity key) key for the dimension tables primary keys. They can use Infa sequence generator, or Oracle sequence, or SQL Server Identity values for the surrogate key.
It is useful because the natural primary key (i.e. Customer Number in Customer table) can change and this makes updates more difficult.

for more information look at this [forum](http://wb.itboards.com/WB/default.asp?action=9&fid=182&read=160934).

Comment: Should a unique surrogate key be assigned for every row in a fact table?

Comment: look here: http://www.kimballgroup.com/2006/07/design-tip-81-fact-table-surrogate-key/